# Get image from service URL in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I have to retrieve image from rest service url.But I don't have a separate URL for image(path of the image).I m getting it in a XML file.I did parsing of XML and stored it in an array.Now I couldn't understand how to retrieve image from it ..
My array looks like this:

```
   (
    {
    Image = "

    9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA7Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcgSlBFRyB2NjIpLCBxdWFsaXR5ID0gODAK/9sAQwAGBAUGBQQGBgUGBwcGCAoQCgoJCQoUDg8MEB
    cUGBgXFBYWGh0lHxobIxwWFiAsICMmJykqKRkfLTAtKDAlKCko/9sAQwEHBwcKCAoTCgoTKBoWGigoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgo/8AAEQgEKwZAAwEiAAIRAQMR
    Af/EAB8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALUQAAIBAwMCBAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RV
    VldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6g4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2drh4uPk5ebn6Onq8fLz9PX29/j5+v/EAB8BAAMBAQEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALURAAIBAgQEAwQHBQQEAAECdwABAgMRBAUhMQYSQVEHYXETIjKBCBRCkaGxwQkjM1LwFWJy0QoWJDThJfEXGBkaJicoKSo1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoKDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uLj5OXm5+jp6vLz9PX29/j5+v/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A9bDUu6qwenB6y
NCyGpQ1Vg9OD0XAsbqA9QlqAeaALOaXNQbqUPQInBpQagDU4NQBMDS5qHdShqAJ80uah3UoagCbNLmod1LupgS5pc1Fupd1AEtLUW6l3UASUtR7qN1MCXNFR7qXdQBJRTN1LmgB9LUe6l3UAPopu6jdQA8UU3dRuoEOxS0zNLmgB1LTM0bqAH0U3dRuoAdRTd1LmgB2KMU3NGaAHYoxTc0u6gBcUYpM0ZoAWikzRmgBcUUmaM0ALRSZpc0AGKKM0ZoAKKM0ZoAKKM0ZoAKKM0ZoAKKM0ZFACUUtBNABSUUUAFFFGaAA0lLRQMSkpaKQCUlLRSATFJS0UAJRS0lABSUtFACUlLRQA2jFLRQA0
ikxTqSgY002n02kMAKkUUwVIopoTJFFPApoFSAVRICnCgUtMAopRRQAUUUUAFJS0UAJRS0lIAooooAKSlpKAFpKKKACilpKACiii
gAooooASiiigAooooASilpKACkpaKAEpKU0UAJRRRQAlIaWikMSkpaKQDaKWkoASilNJQAlJSmigBtJTqSkMaaSnUhoGNNJTjSUgEFPWminCmA4U4UgpwpoQopRSCnUCFFOFNpwpgxRS0UuKYhhqNhUpqNhQBXcVVlq3IKqy1LGVyOaeopAMmrEceaEhNkZ4FR5JNW3i4pscGWq7E3GRoTU6Rmp44farkdvkdKdgK0MXNXYoulSRwY7VajjwKkYxI6mRBT
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
         //big array </Image>
        }
        )
```

I couldn't understand what format(byte array or base64?) is this coming from service?
How to retrieve image from this in a tableViewCell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format is base64 then you should decode this string into data and get image. Use [nsdata+ base64 class](https://github.com/kgn/NSData-Base64) and import those class in your project.

Use `+ (NSData *)decodeBase64WithString:(NSString *)strBase64;` method in your code. call like  this

```
 NSData *imageData = [NSData decodeBase64WithString:strBase64];
```

**Edit:**

```
 NSString *yourBase64String = [yourDictionary valueForKey:@"Image"];
 NSData *imageData = [NSData decodeBase64WithString:yourBase64String];
 UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: should i import nsdata+base64.h and nsdata+base64.m i.e only two classes from that link?

Comment: Yes. These two classes are enough and add in your project then use #import "NSData+Base64.h"

Comment: + (NSData *)decodeBase64WithString:(NSString *)strBase64
{
 NSData *imageData = [NSData decodeBase64WithString:strBase64];

} wrote like this but getting a orange coloured line below [NSData decodeBase64WithString:strBase64]; GETTING A WARNING LIKE THIS :Class method +decodeBase64WithString:not found(return type equals to 'id') and actually I need to display that image in uitableviewcell.So what to do?I made NSMutableDictionary from NSMutableArray in -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ }..How should I proceed further ?

Comment: Write  NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:yourBase64String]; it in -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method.

Answer (score 1):

If this is base64 string then You can decode base64 string to NSData using [this](https://github.com/mikeho/QSUtilities) and you can access UIImage from NSData.

```
+ (NSData *)decodeBase64WithString:(NSString *)strBase64;
```

Comment: Can u please tell me how can i recognise whether it is base46 string?

Comment: UIImage *img =  [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        if (img)
        {
            NSLog(@"string is valid base64");
        }

Comment: + (NSData *)decodeBase64WithString:(NSString *)strBase64 { NSData *imageData = [NSData decodeBase64WithString:strBase64]; } wrote like this but getting a orange coloured line below [NSData decodeBase64WithString:strBase64]; GETTING A WARNING LIKE THIS :Class method +decodeBase64WithString:not found(return type equals to 'id') and actually I need to display that image in uitableviewcell.So what to do?I made NSMutableDictionary from NSMutableArray in -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { }..How should I proceed further ?

Answer (score 0):

May be it is because there were modifications to the NSData+Base64 files but the method now is dataFromBase64String instead of decodeBase64WithString